# How do I effectively fill gaps with between window mesh and window frame?

Tags: windows, weatherstripping

I'm attempting to reasonably insect-proof my house as I sleep with the windows open at night (no AC).  The windows in our house has a retractable mesh screen attached to the frame that has a slight gap at the bottom, which I'd like to fill.

I've been able to close some of the windows with a [foam weatherstrip](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000SKYON6).  However, some gaps are large enough (> 1 inch) that the foam doesn't cover it fully.  Layering two foam strips on top of each other doesn't seem effective as the adhesive doesn't stick to foam properly.  My guess is that it won't stand the test of time.

My questions are two fold:

1. Is there foam > 1 inch thick, that'd suit my needs?  I've been unsuccessful in finding them in retail stores like HD.
2. Is there any other material that'd suit my needs?  Bonus if it's paint-able to match my window frame color.

A picture is worth a thousand words, so: [image: here's the gap that I want to fill]

[image: Zoom-up of frame joints]

[image: Wider perspective]

Comment: I think I'd be adding a strip of plastic or aluminum to the bottom of the screen panel. Is that an option for you?

Comment: @isherwood Could you link to a part please?   I'm not sure how I'd add some aluminum to the bottom of the panel without it being flimsy.

Comment: Also realize that screens allow rain water to come in when the windows are closed (or not).  So there must be some way for it to drain out of that sill area.  As you close the gap, leave some "weep" holes.

Answer (score 4):

The foam weatherstripping you linked is 1.5 inches (38 mm) wide. Just turn it sideways and attach it to the face of the bottom of the screen instead of to the top of the sill. If you had 0.5 inches (12.5 mm) of material hanging off the bottom of the window you'd still have 1 inch (25 mm) of material stuck to the frame. I'd put some staples in it just to make sure it doesn't fall off, but you're not looking for a super tight seal here, just something to stop bugs from crawling in.

:EDIT: - Like this:

[image]

Comment: This is the gist of what I was asking about above, but I'd maybe use rigid material instead of foam. A strip of vinyl, plastic, or aluminum attached with double-sided foam tape might be more robust.

Comment: I considered this, but ruled it out on aesthetic grounds.  I'm not sure if I can spray paint foam or not.  If I can, then this would work.

Comment: @R.D. then you should put that in the post lol. If aesthetics are an issue for you then I'd do basically the same thing, but with a strip of wood or aluminum. Then you can paint/stain it whatever you want. Might also want to investigate why the screen doesn't come down all the way. I can't tell, but it looks like it might be made to slide up and down. Could just be stuck on an acorn or dead bug or something.